# HubSpot Embedded Form - Move labels below the inputs breaking form

Tags: javascript, jquery, hubspot

I'm manipulating the DOM with jquery in the HubSpot form embed code. I'm trying to move the labels below the inputs to achieve the CSS styles I need.

```
<script>
    hbspt.forms.create({
        portalId: "xxxxx",
        formId: "xxxx",
        cssClass: '',
        cssRequired: 'form__field required',
        errorClass: 'form__field',
        errorMessageClass: 'error',
        submitButtonClass: 'submitBTN',
        onFormReady: function ($form) {
            $('form').wrapInner('<div class="form-row form_block"></div>')
            $('.hs-form-field').addClass('form-group col-md-12');
            $('input').addClass('form__field');
            $('label').addClass('form__label');
            $(".input input").each(function () {
                var e = $(this);
                e.parent().parent().find('label').insertAfter(e);
            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

However, I'm running into an issue. With an error that's not very helpful. When a field isn't valid, then trying to go back into the field to edit, I get the below JS error. One error for each letter I type.

```
v2.js:4 Uncaught Error: Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.
    at r (v2.js:4)
    at Object.processUpdates (v2.js:1)
    at Object.dangerouslyProcessChildrenUpdates [as processChildrenUpdates] (v2.js:2)
    at s (v2.js:3)
    at a.updateChildren (v2.js:3)
    at a._updateDOMChildren (v2.js:2)
    at a.updateComponent (v2.js:2)
    at a.receiveComponent (v2.js:2)
    at Object.receiveComponent (v2.js:3)
    at u._updateRenderedComponent (v2.js:2)
```

When I remove the label insertAfter() script those errors go away. I also posted in the HubSpot community, I will update answers each place.

https://community.hubspot.com/t5/APIs-Integrations/Move-labels-below-the-inputs-in-Embedded-Form/td-p/354385

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the form should be edited on the HubSpot side and not so much on a code level. If you really want to hack it on a code level, simply increase your specificity to override the HubSpot form default configured styles.

Example:

```
.someParentClass .hs-form-field {
    position: relative;
}

.someParentClass [id*="label-xxx"] {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
}
```

Where `.someParentClass` is a parent of the HubSpot form and `[id*="label-xxx"]` is the label you want to move down.